# Flash AS3: Change variables depending on current frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, actionscript, charts

OK so I have this code which creates a pie chart...

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip; 

public class App extends MovieClip {
    function App() {
        this.graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xFF0000);
        this.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.5);
        this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, -90, 0);
        this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, 0, 110);
        this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, 110, 180);
        this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, 180, 270);
        this.graphics.endFill();
    }


var piesize:Number = 140;   

    var wedge1:Number = 90;
    var wedge2:Number = 110;
    var wedge3:Number = 90;
    var wedge4:Number = 90;


    /**
     * Draw a segment of a circle
     * @param target    <Sprite> The object we want to draw into
     * @param x         <Number> The x-coordinate of the origin of the segment
     * @param y         <Number> The y-coordinate of the origin of the segment
     * @param r         <Number> The radius of the segment
     * @param aStart    <Number> The starting angle (degrees) of the segment (0 = East)
     * @param aEnd      <Number> The ending angle (degrees) of the segment (0 = East)
     * @param step      <Number=1> The number of degrees between each point on the segment's circumference
     */
    function drawSegment(target:Sprite, x:Number, y:Number, r:Number, aStart:Number, aEnd:Number, step:Number = 1):void {
            // More efficient to work in radians
            var degreesPerRadian:Number = Math.PI / 180;
            aStart *= degreesPerRadian;
            aEnd *= degreesPerRadian;
            step *= degreesPerRadian;

            // Draw the segment
            target.graphics.moveTo(x, y);
            for (var theta:Number = aStart; theta < aEnd; theta += Math.min(step, aEnd - theta)) {
                target.graphics.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(theta), y + r * Math.sin(theta));
            }
            target.graphics.lineTo(x + r * Math.cos(aEnd), y + r * Math.sin(aEnd));
            target.graphics.lineTo(x, y);
    };
}
}
```

This code is pulled from an external AS file as recommended. That works fine, and creates a lovely red pie chart with 4 segments.

You will see the variables wedge1, wedge2 etc. which currently don't do anything although I would like to be able to change those variables on each frame of  my main timeline.

Is there a way of putting those variables on the main timeline in a way in which it will change those variables in the pie chart when I move between those frames? (I'll just be using the left and right keys to move forward and back a frame at a time)

Also I will have to change the code somehow to achieve this result... I have written it SUDO style but any help with the exact execution of this code would be greatly appreciated...

```
wedge1start == -90
wedge1end == wedge1start + wedge1
wedge2end == wedge1end + wedge2
wedge3end == wedge2end + wedge3
wedge4end == wedge2end + wedge4


this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge1start, wedge1end);
this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge1end, wedge2end);
this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge2end, wedge3end);
this.drawSegment(this, stage.stageWidth/2, stage.stageHeight/2, piesize, wedge3end, wedge4end);
```

I hope this makes sense, I'm basically trying to achieve the pie chart segments and size changing as i move forwards or backwards through the time. The variables exist but I can't seem to be able to change them from outside that AS file.

Should I be using an on enter frame or something??

Thanks for your help, sorry for the long question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the class you posted is your document class,  all you need to do is make your variables `public`:

```
public var wedge1:Number = 0;
```

Then on your main timeline you can access them by name like in your pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks. I have now actually got the variable changing on the 2nd and 4th frame of my animation. HOWEVER what I've been missing all along is the pie being created on enter frame. I tried adding the ENTER_FRAME listener around the 'function App' but every time I get an error because something or other is undefined.
I understand the stage isnt defined but don't understand how to define it or define something to put this action in! I'm stuck

Comment: stage gets defined automatically when things are added to the display list.  you can listen for it with the `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` event. I can help you out more tomorrow if you're still having issues.

Comment: OK so I got the pie chart being drawn every frame now so the 'piesize' affects the sizing of it. what I didnt realise is that sprite wouldnt dissapear so I have hundreds of pie charts loading on top of each other, which creates some strange results... Now I just need to figure out how to remove that piechart before its reloaded and I'm on my way there... If you could help me out tomorrow that would be amazing, I have no problem paying for your time. I'll message you now. Thanks

Comment: It appears I can't message you, if you could send me ur contact to pete at gogeye dot com it would be very much appreciated. thanks

Comment: No need for direct messaging or payment.  Are you drawing your pie charts on the same sprite, or a new sprite each time?  Can you update your question to include the code your using to create a new pie chart - in your pseudo code your drawing it to your document class.

Comment: If it is your document class being passed to your `drawSegment` function everytime,  you just need to clear the graphics object: `graphics.clear()` before you create a new pie.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed. I stumbled accross it myself this morning and I'm closer to achieving what I want. I'm now onto a whole new problem with calculating percentages and setting them as my variables. I guess thats a whole other question. Thanks for your help